# Xml error: Wrong charset?

Tags: php, xml, encoding, character-encoding, domdocument

I'm trying to generate a xml file via php with DOMDocument. But there are some "weird" characters in there so it gives me a encoding error. `error on line 2 at column 81: Encoding error`.

I'm trying to put ``` [0.3e](¯``·._.·[name]·._.·´¯) ``` in there.

I'm parsing it as follows

```
header( 'content-type: text/xml' );
$domTree = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );
```

and `echo $domTree->saveXML();` at the end.

Output is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server><errors/><info><value>0</value><value>25</value><value>30</value><value>[0.3e](
```

Hope you can help tell me what I'm doing wrong here or which charset to use.

David

Comment: Where do you get the xml from?

Comment: I retrieve the info from a game server. The weird characters are part of the server name.

Comment: That's not my point sorry, I mean show the code how you get it

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1Z3pVjNZ

Comment: Yeah you need to know what encoding the response will be in, it's not UTF-8 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to force the encoding of the input string and escape out any remaining entities as HTML entities:

```
$enc = mb_detect_encoding($text);
$text = @mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8',$enc);      
$text = htmlentities($text,ENT_IGNORE,'UTF-8');
```

Comment: `error on line 2 at column 94: Entity 'macr' not defined` Copied the code exactly. Changed $text to $value

Comment: XML does not define **html** entities

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are getting the data from is not giving it to you in UTF-8. I assume it's Windows-1252 but I could be wrong.

```
header( 'content-type: text/xml' );
$domTree = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'Windows-1252' );
```

Answer (score -2):

Use CData section in xml nodes!

Comment: I see this downvoted but I'm curious why this is wrong? (Didn't test it.)